# Android Google Map - How to access user's location if permissions are granted

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, permissions, location

I'm building a Jetpack Compose app that requires access to user's current location. Here's my code for now.

```
val userDefaultLocation = LatLng(0.0, 0.0) // Default location

val locationPermissionsState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
    listOf(
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    )
)

val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
    if (locationPermissionsState.allPermissionsGranted) {
        position = ???
    } else {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(userDefaultLocation, 11f)
    }
}
```

I'm using the Accompanist api and I have the corresponding permissions added in the Manifest file. Now my question is, if allPermissionsGranted is true, how can I access the user's location as a LatLng object. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `onMyLocationClick` lambda or the `onMyLocationButtonClick` lambda of `GoogleMaps()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you just want to get the last known user location you can use `FusedLocationProviderClient`

You can find the official documentation following the below link
[https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#:~:text=The%20fused%20location%20provider%20is,device's%20use%20of%20battery%20power](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#:%7E:text=The%20fused%20location%20provider%20is,device%27s%20use%20of%20battery%20power).

A simple implementation would look like this:

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
        }
}
```